# ERROR: Could not determine java version from 'JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8'

Tags: java, android, cordova, version, phonegap

Could anyone help me please ?

"ERROR: Could not determine java version from 'JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8'."

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
```

Comment: Error:(21, 0) Could not find method compileJava() for arguments [build_8ht3yju753mfaonj2cjy140ok$_run_closure1@5df54936] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
<a href="openFile:/Users/jalal/Desktop/my-app/platforms/android/app/build.gradle">Open File</a>